# Speed up this query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have this query, which takes 117 seconds to get 100,000 rows:

```
 SELECT 
`nas`.`nasname`,
`nas`.`api_username`,
`nas`.`api_password`,
`nas`.`api_port`,
`nas`.`secret`,
`nas`.`up_by`,
COALESCE(`nas`.`api_is_enabled`,'0') as `api_is_en`,
`radacct`.`nasipaddress`,
`radcheck`.`address_list_name`,
`radcheck`.`address_val`,
`radacct`.`framedipaddress`,
`radacct`.`callingstationid`,
`radacct`.`radacctid` as `id_session`,
`radacct`.`framedprotocol`,
`radacct`.`username`,
`radacct`.`last_speed` ,
`radacct`.`acctsessionid` as `acctsessionid`,
`radip`.`value` as `ip_address`,
`radmac`.`value` as `mac_address`,
`radcount`.`value` as `simul_sess`,
COUNT(`radacct`.`radacctid`) as count_login ,
COALESCE(`card_users`.`id`,0) as `id_card`,
COALESCE(`card_users`.`download_qouta`,`userinfo`.`in_down`) *1024*1024 as `down_qouta`,
COALESCE(`card_users`.`upload_qouta`,`userinfo`.`in_up`) *1024*1024 as `up_qouta`,
COALESCE(`card_users`.`all_quota`,`userinfo`.`av_qouta`) *1024*1024 as `av_qouta`,
`card_users`.`date_end_card` as `date_end_card`,
`card_users`.`val_date` as `val_date`,
`card_users`.`per_second` as `per_second`,
`card_users`.`at_the_first_login` as `at_the_first_login`,
`card_users`.`exp_first_login` as `exp_first_login`,
`card_users`.`val_time_exp` as `val_time_exp`,
`card_users`.`time_cards_exp` as `time_cards_exp`,
`card_users`.`exp_quota` as `exp_quota`,
`card_users`.`exp_date` as `exp_date`,
`userinfo`.`updatedate` as `updatedate`,
`userinfo`.`divi_down_speed_slm` as `divi_down_speed_slm`,
`userinfo`.`divi_up_speed_slm` as `divi_up_speed_slm`,
`userinfo`.`arr_days` as `u_arr_days`,
`userinfo`.`value_choice` as `u_value_choice`,
`userinfo`.`last_end_day` as `last_end_day`,
`userinfo`.`macs` as `macs`,
 `p`.`profile_name` as `profile_name`,
`p`.`daily_down_qouta`*1024*1024 as `down_daily_qouta`,
`p`.`daily_up_qouta`*1024*1024 as `up_daily_qouta`,
`p`.`daily_profile_qouta`*1024*1024 as `daily_profile_qouta`,
`p`.`online_time` as `online_time`,
`p`.`hours_min` as `hours_min`,
`p`.`daily_online_time` as `daily_online_time`,
`p`.`daily_hours_min` as `daily_hours_min`,
`p`.`bandwidth_time` as `bandwidth_time`,
`p`.`daily_expire_service` as `daily_expire_service`,
`p`.`qouta_expire_service` as `qouta_expire_service`,
`p`.`profile_expire_service` as `profile_expire_service`,
`p`.`sp_up` as `sp_up`,
`p`.`sp_down` as `sp_down`,
`p`.`ch_day_end` as `ch_day_end`,
`p`.`set_day_end` as `set_day_end`,
`p`.`percent` as `percent`,
`p`.`arr_days` as `p_arr_days`,
`p`.`value_choice` as `p_value_choice`,
`r1`.`value` as `value_exp`,
`p1`.`bandwidth_time` as `band_exp`,
`p1`.`percent` as `percent_exp`,
`r2`.`value` as `val_address_exp_list`,
`r3`.`value` as `value_exp_daily`,
`p3`.`bandwidth_time` as `band_daily_exp`,
`p3`.`percent` as `percent_daily_exp`,
`r4`.`value` as `val_address_exp_daily_list`,
`r5`.`value` as `value_exp_serv`,
`p3`.`bandwidth_time` as `band_serv_exp`,
`p3`.`percent` as `percent_serv_exp`,
`r6`.`value` as `val_address_exp_serv_list`,
`r7`.`value` as `value_now`,
`r8`.`value` as `val_address_list`,
COALESCE(ROUND(time_to_sec(`userinfo`.`online_time`)),0) as `t_online_time` ,
COALESCE(ROUND(time_to_sec(`userinfo`.`daily_online_time`)),0) as `d_online_time`,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`radexp`.`value`, '%d %b %Y %H:%i')) as `exp_user`,
`radacct`.`callingstationid` as  `callingstationid`,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`radacct`.`acctstarttime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) as `session_st_date`
FROM `radacct`
INNER JOIN `radcheck` 
    ON `radacct`.`username` = `radcheck`.`username` 
   AND `radcheck`.`attribute` = 'Cleartext-Password' 
INNER JOIN `radusergroup` `r9` 
    ON `r9`.`username` = `radcheck`.`username`
LEFT JOIN `userinfo` 
    ON `userinfo`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(`radacct`.`acctinputoctets`) as `up_today`
         , SUM(`radacct`.`acctoutputoctets`) as `down_today`
         , SUM(`radacct`.`acctsessiontime`) as `daily_time`
         , `radacct`.`username` 
    FROM `radacct` 
    WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`acctstarttime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') 
    GROUP BY `username`
) as `rad2` 
    ON `rad2`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
INNER JOIN `nas` 
    ON `nas`.`nasname`=`radacct`.`nasipaddress` 
LEFT JOIN `profiles` `p` 
    ON `p`.`profile_name` = `r9`.`groupname`
LEFT JOIN `profiles` `p1` 
    ON `p1`.`id` = `p`.`qouta_expire_service`
LEFT JOIN `profiles` `p2` 
    ON `p2`.`id` = `p`.`daily_expire_service`
LEFT JOIN `profiles` `p3` 
    ON `p3`.`id` = `p`.`profile_expire_service`
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r1` 
    ON `r1`.`groupname` = `p1`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r1`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r2` 
    ON `r2`.`groupname` = `p1`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r2`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Address-List'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r3` 
    ON `r3`.`groupname` = `p2`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r3`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r4` 
    ON `r4`.`groupname` = `p2`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r4`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Address-List' 
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r5` 
    ON `r5`.`groupname` = `p3`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r5`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r6` 
    ON `r6`.`groupname` = `p3`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r6`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Address-List'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r7` 
    ON `r7`.`groupname` = `p`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r7`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Rate-Limit'
LEFT JOIN `radgroupreply` `r8` 
    ON `r8`.`groupname` = `p`.`profile_name` 
   AND `r8`.`attribute` = 'Mikrotik-Address-List'
LEFT JOIN `card_users` 
    ON `card_users`.`id` = `radcheck`.`id_card`
LEFT JOIN `radreply` as `radip` 
    ON `radip`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
   AND `radip`.`attribute`='Framed-IP-Address'
LEFT JOIN `radcheck` as `radmac` 
    ON `radmac`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
   AND `radmac`.`attribute`='Calling-Station-Id'
LEFT JOIN `radcheck` as `radcount` 
    ON `radcount`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
   AND `radcount`.`attribute`='Simultaneous-Use'
LEFT JOIN `radcheck` as `radexp` 
    ON `radexp`.`username` = `r9`.`username` 
   AND `radexp`.`attribute`='Expiration'
WHERE ( radacct .AcctStopTime IS NULL 
    OR radacct.AcctStopTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
GROUP BY `radacct`.`username`
```

#### Explain

[image]

#### Problem

When I remove this from the query it speeds up by 60%:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(`radacct`.`acctinputoctets`) as `up_today`, 
SUM(`radacct`.`acctoutputoctets`) as `down_today`,
SUM(`radacct`.`acctsessiontime`) as `daily_time`,
`radacct`.`username` FROM `radacct` 
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`acctstarttime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') 
GROUP BY `username`) as `rad2` ON (`rad2`.`username` = `r9`.`username`)
```

I am using `STR_TO_DATE(`acctstarttime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d')` to get the date without hours, minutes, and seconds to get daily time and daily quota.

Comment: All tables with columns `attribute` and `value` should be examined to see whether it is possible to replace them with properly designed tables. Sometimes EAV (Entity Attribute Value) is necessary but in many situations, they can be replaced  with better alternatives. At a glance you can remove ~10 JOINS from your query with another design. Are you sure you get a correct result from your query? I.e. can all attributes in the SELECT clause of the query be uniquely identified by radacct.username?

Comment: Is the output result set 100000 lines long?  Or do you mean that some input table has that many rows?

Answer (score 2):

`radgroupreply` looks like the typical "attribute" table of an EAV schema.  EAV does not scale well.

See my tips on how to improve the schema at http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

If you need help addapting it to your table, let's see your `SHOW CREATE TABLE radgroupreply`.

The main benefit will come from making the `PRIMARY KEY` *start with* `(groupname, attribute, ...)`

As for that `LEFT JOIN ( derived table )` slowing things down,...  Can you get rid of "`LEFT`"?  That would let the Optimizer perform that subquery first rather than repeatedly.

Where practical, don't "hide" a potentially-indexable column inside a function.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`acctstarttime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d') =
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

If `acctstarttime` is a `VARCHAR`, then seriously consider converting to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` it as you store it, not as you try to use it.

If it is already `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, then this should be the same:

```
    acctstarttime >= CURDATE()
AND acctstarttime  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

And, if you don't have any values in the future, then simply:

```
    acctstarttime >= CURDATE()
```

With either of the last two formulations, the `LEFT JOIN` can probably benefit a lot from adding this to `radacct`:

```
INDEX(acctstarttime)
```

This is inconsistent with the other uses of `profiles`:

```
LEFT JOIN  `profiles` `p`  ON `p`.`profile_name` = `r9`.`groupname`
```

If it is correct, then you need

```
INDEX(profile_name)
```

Comment: Two thumbs up for your cookbook @Rick James. Found it really interesting.